# Web intelligence formula round time to hours

Tags: business-objects

Is there a formula in web intelligence that can be used to return only the whole hour number from a date timestamp? As in if the number is rounded down? I have achieved the same in SQL but when I use the measure in the business objects report I receive #MUTLIVALUE error

For example

01/11/2021 11:30:49

Requirement is to make this appear as

01/11/2021 11:00:00

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting a #MULTIVALUE, but you can do this in WebI with the [FormatDate()](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/10/24/formatdate-functions-with-different-parameters/) function. Here are two possibilities. The actual formula is just the equal sign and everything to the right of it.

```
Current DateTime Hour Only - AM/PM=FormatDate([Current DateTime];"MM/dd/yyyy hh:00:00 a")
    
Current DateTime Hour Only - 24 Hour=FormatDate([Current DateTime];"MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked and gave me what I needed. Thanks!